# Greedy Algorithms and append function - how to create a new array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, greedy

Okay, so I have an array coin and I want to create a new array which is the same length as array, but with the amount of coins from the array 'coins' needed for input m.

```
coin = [200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
```

So far, I have the following. What should be in for loop for me to return what I want?

```
def coinSplitGD2(m):

    coin = [200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]

    if m==0:
        return 0
    for i in range(len(coin)):
        if coin...
```

So if m is 143, it will return `[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]` meaning no 200-coins, one 100-coin, no
50-coins, two 20-coins, no 10-coins, no 5-coins, one 2-coin and one 1-coin

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: So if m is 143, it will return [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1] meaning no 200-coins, one 100-coin, no 50-coins, two 20-coins, no 10-coins, no 5-coins, one 2-coin and one 1-coin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coin = [200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
def coinSplitGD2(m):
    a = []
    for c in coin:
        a.append(m // c)
        m %= c
    return a
```

so that:

```
coinSplitGD2(143)
```

returns:

```
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```